# Java: Not specifying type in when instantiating objects

Tags: java

What is the practical difference between

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

and

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Neither throw any warnings and both seem to work fine ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second notation is called *diamond operator*, and was introducted in Java 7 as part of the project Coin ([JSR 334](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=334)).

There is no pratical difference between the two notations, it just save our tired fingers from few keybord entries :)

[A good article about this is available on javaworld](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html)

Comment: Yes there's a difference: the second one is shorter :)